# Using only TrackRenderer of Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to implement an app where I only get to use the TrackRenderers (e.g. MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer) of exoplayer. I know modularity is a major aspect of ExoPlayer but in my case I don't want to customize them, I just want to use the TrackRenderers with some encoded video that I have.  A working implementation or a guide would be very helpful.